# asp sqldatasource text

Tags: asp.net, sql

I need to have a sqldatasource with the following sql in it.

```
if @filter = 'departments'
begin

SELECT ISNULL(DocTitle,'') as Name, DocNumber as id, DocUrl+DocName AS link,LastModBy,LastModDate, IsLink 
FROM cmc.CMC_Docs d 
INNER JOIN CMC.CMC_Doc_Locations as l on l.FamilyID = d.FamilyID 
INNER JOIN CMC.CMC_DocFamilies df on df.FamilyID = d.FamilyId 
WHERE IsEnabled=1 
AND ISNULL(DocName,'') <> '' 
AND d.FamilyID IN @dep  
ORDER by DocTitle

end
```

where @dep is something like (2,3)

However when I try to test the query I get an error saying incorrect syntax near @dep.

Any ideas how I need to write this inside of the datasource in order for it to work?

Thanks,

Comment: as far as im aware this would only be possible with a dynamic sql query concatenated from strings. Or, have a nested query that could do the filter for you.

Comment: try:SELECT ISNULL(DocTitle,'') as Name, DocNumber as id, DocUrl+DocName AS link,LastModBy,LastModDate, IsLink 
FROM cmc.CMC_Docs d 
INNER JOIN CMC.CMC_Doc_Locations as l on l.FamilyID = d.FamilyID 
INNER JOIN CMC.CMC_DocFamilies df on df.FamilyID = d.FamilyId 
WHERE IsEnabled=1 
AND ISNULL(DocName,'') <> '' 
AND d.FamilyID IN ( @dep )
ORDER by DocTitle

Comment: If you are trying to have a parameterized in clause - [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterizing-an-sql-in-clause) may be helpful.

Comment: Goose's comment is correct. The approach I take is David Basarab's answer. I like it because it is SQL based - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterizing-an-sql-in-clause/337752#337752

Answer (score 0):

do you need to put this in ()?

ex: select * from product where productid in (1,2,3) works 
ex: select * from product where productid in 1,2,3 - does not work

Comment: the variable @dep = (2,3), it includes the curlys.